# Grouping and summing only n variables of m with m>n using a column as key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df`

```
df_dict = {"week":[1,1,1,4,5],
           "store":["A","B","C","A","C"],
           "var": [1,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)


    week    store   var
0   1       A       1
1   1       B       1
2   1       C       1
3   4       A       1
4   5       C       1
```

My goal is to sum variable `A` and `C` by week, but not variable `B`.

```
df["store"] = df["store"].str.replace("A","X")
df["store"] = df["store"].str.replace("C","X")
```

And this is the final output

```
df.groupby(by=["week","store"]).sum().reset_index()

week    store   var
0   1       B   1
1   1       X   2
2   4       X   1
3   5       X   1
```

The code works perfectly but I am pretty sure there is a better way to do that in `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably my biggest issue with the current implementation is that `X` is not a very good placeholder - we should prefer `NaN` instead - and even over `B`, you still sum. I would sooner split the data between grouped and non-grouped, with no `store` replacement:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "week": (1,1,1,4,5),
    "store": ("A","B","C","A","C"),
    "var": (1,1,1,1,1),
})

should_group = df.store != 'B'
totals = (
    df[should_group]
    .groupby('week')['var']
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)

result = pd.concat((
    df[~should_group], totals
), ignore_index=True)

print(result)
```

```
   week store  var
0     1     B    1
1     1   NaN    2
2     4   NaN    1
3     5   NaN    1
```

Comment: You are right for the `X` issue, I omitted some details. The reason is because `X`, in my actual problem, is just the aggregation of two stores and at the end I have to save an `.xlsx` file where this can be understandable (Eg. In week 1 X contributed for 2) . But I can add a `.replace()` at the end after the manipulation.